# how to find which query failed in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to build an app with subscription basis, so I've a table which consists of name as string, valid_till as date.

I'm trying to fetch the table by following:

```
$today = Carbon::today();
$active = Domain::where([
            ['name', $name],
            ['valid_till', '>=', $today],
    ])->first();
if(isset($active))
{
    return "Name fetched";
}
else
{
    return "Name not there";
}
```

It is working properly. I want to check the error like "name found but validity expired". Please guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use the already pre-built validation mechanism?

Comment: @DainisAbols I'm learning new things in this, I'm not aware of many of its functionality

Comment: Laravel has [Validator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation) that you can use to validate different data. It's commonly presented and used for request validation, but you can feed it basically anything. Just define the rules and read the validation errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`first()` will return `null` if query founds nothing, so use `is_null` to check if there is object or not.

```
if (!is_null($active)) {
    // Object exists.
} else {
    // No result.
}
```

When you're using `get()` you should use `result->isEmpty()` or `empty($result)` or `count($result)` or `$result->count()` to check if collection is empty or not.

Comment: This is not my answer. Suppose it fetches the name and gets the output but during valid_till check it throws error. i want to catch those error.

Comment: @NitishKumar when `valid_till` is later than today, your query will return `null` as I described in my answer.

Comment: I want to show this error that your subscription is expired or name not found.

Comment: @NitishKumar in this case, just search by name. If name is not found, it will give you `null`. If name will be found, do another check like `if( $active->valid_till >= Carbon::now())`. If `valid_till` is not in `$dates` property of the model, use Carbon's `parse()` method to create an instance from the date.